# Lines are shifted around when creating and saving records through Add rows Button in interactive grid oracle Apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, interactive-grid

For Ex: I have 5 existing lines as line no "1,2,3,4,5" and now i am trying to add one more row as "6" and try to save then the rows are shifted around while saving records through "Add rows" Button as "4,3,5,6,1,2" in interactive grid oracle Apex, the rows are automatically shifting the order, how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, rows in a table aren't "sorted" in any particular order. The only way to make sure they will be sorted properly is to apply the **ORDER BY** clause.

As you can't do it in Interactive Grid's query (if you used it), you'll have to do it through Interactive Grid's **Actions** button (Data > Sort) and choose one (or more) columns which will *sort* rows in the Interactive Grid.

Comment: I have ordered by seq no in my grid still the rows are getting shiffted

Comment: What happens when you **refresh** the page (press F5)?

Comment: Hi i have a page there in header i have some records need to enter then i have a grid for lines.... first i will enter the header data then come for the grid i entered 2 lines and saved the lines are getting changed ....what i entered 1st is coming in second line and second entered in going to first line